# Why can't I Set-Location (cd) to the object returned by Get-ChildItem? (aka ls, dir)

Tags: powershell

```
ls "d:\" "yasuo500" -recurse -directory
```

This command finds the folder 'yasuo500' in d:\media\documents, I want to use 'cd' to get into that directory, but how? i tried this:

```
$path1 = ls "d:\" "yasuo500" -recurse -directory
cd $path1
```

But it does not work, it says `cd : cannot find path 'c:\yasuo500' because it does not exist.`

What am I doing wrong?

*Keep in mind I can just do

```
cd "d:\media\documents\yasuo500"
```

But... it's not efficient, what if the directory is LONG, i'd take me too much typing.

Comment: I am not really clear what you are actually asking. You have the answer you need in your question (or so it seems to me), and the examples/output you give isn't really lining up (your directory is moving from c: to d:). I may be missing something, but I am not sure what anyone can really add to help you, nor how this is a serious issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need: `cd $path1.FullName`

`PowerShell` operates on objects, and it's important to understand how these work together.

`cd` is an alias for `Set-Location`.
`get-help Set-Location` indicates it expects a string for the path:

> Set-Location **[[-Path] < string >]** [-PassThru] [-UseTransaction] 
>   []

That means when you pass it an object, it will cast the object to a string.

`$path1` is a `DirectoryInfo`, and if you call `$path1.ToString()` you'll get just the yasuo500 part of the path.  It's the equivalent of `cd yasuo500` and the error indicates you tried doing that from the root of your C:\.

Using the `FullName` property of your DirectoryInfo gives a full path string.

Comment: thanks for the answer, not only does this work, but you explained why my method did not work, thanks!